# Accessing array makes UITableView to lag when scrolling

Tags: ios7, swift, xcode6, ios7.1

UITableView lags when scrolling, it's the fault of this line of code (called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method)

```
lCell?.showContent(mContent[indexPath.row] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>);
```

I removed all code from `showContent` method but it still lags, the issue I think is 
when the array is accessed. If I pass an empty `Dictionary`

```
lCell?.showContent([:]);
```

It works fine, no lags when tableview is scrolled. mContent is an `Array` of `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`. It has 47 elements (Dictionaries) which don't
contain large amount of data (some short strings, some ints)

How can I avoid lags when tableView is scrolled ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just that when the cell gets actual values from the dictionary it has to do expensive layout operations? You can use Instruments to get an immediate definitive breakdown of costs rather than proceeding with trial and error.

Comment: as I said, I removed all the code from showContent method, but the tableview still lags

Comment: Regardless of my failings at fully reading a question, you should still run Instruments and see what it says.

Comment: I did, http://postimg.org/image/6wmihx6s9/ Think many operations are performed on array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After new beta (Xcode beta 5) update, I'm not facing this issue anymore. I think it was an internal performance issue of Dictionary which use AnyObject values.